# Looking For Jquery Gallery Plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

Hey guys I am looking for a free/paid jQuery plugin just like this one: http://idaniphotography.com/personal/

Also, would be nice if you know any which is responsive.

Comment: FancyBox - jQuery Plugin
Simple and fancy lightbox alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Using CSS from [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com/)

Comment: Ok, but how did he manage to show the prev and next pictures?

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer. It's in the Api. Thanks!